# Python terminal not working for for loops

Tags: command-line, 12.10, python

I ran this code in the Python terminal:

```
>>> for news in news_list:
...     print news("li", {"class", "first"})[0].a["href"]
...     
...
```

I want to be able to close this for loop in the terminal, but I have no idea how to. I tried pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace. Can you explain what you are trying to do in the print statement?

Comment: Sorry the brace should have been there. I'm looping through an array that has html data in it. It works, I just don't know how to close the loop in the terminal.

Comment: It seems you are using some nested Data Structures. I can't tell what is the problem without looking at the whole code. Please attach the whole code.

Comment: enter twice works for me. Make sure the 2nd enter is untabbed

Comment: I see this is a console. Can you do `print news` and `print news_list` before that and give us the output? We'll get an idea of the datastructures there.

Answer (score 16):

It doesn't matter what data he is working on. Either way you're just using `print "spam"` or some complicated expression, the for-loop should be closed after two enters or a Python exception will be raised either with bad data or a syntax error.

The problem is you're indenting the empty lines, so the interpreter thinks you're still going to give it some code.

See the difference in below code snippet (select the text to see why):

```
>>> for x in range(4):
...     print x
... 
0
1
2
3
>>> for x in range(4):
...     print x
...     
...     
...     
... 
0
1
2
3
>>>
```

Comment: An aside: Check out `bpython`. It is a command-line python interpreter with keyword suggestions, auto indentation, memory of history across sessions, an option to save code to a file, etc. The first two features make it a killer app. So many times I've pressed tab in the default interpreter only to find a tab on the screen!

Comment: @SPrasanth, you mean [`ipython`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232923/ipython-or-bpython)?

Comment: @warwaruk No, bpython https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bpython/ Will look into ipython though.